# How to find value in more than one field using mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to write an assignment statement such that,

Suppose the value `"wiki"` appears in the options object, I am trying to match documents that have the value of 'wiki' in either the "overview" field or "tag_list" field of the below documents.

can some one guide me I want to use the `$or` operator to do this?

the documents are from `crunchbase` database.

and the application is using node.js driver.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a sample document?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is depend on the Driver. But i will provide the answer for mongo shell.

you can use `db.options.find( { $or: [ { overview: "wiki" }, { tag_list: "wiki" } ] } )`

Answer (score 0):

the question was on Node.js driver.
and the answer was : 
query['$or'] = [ {'overview':{"$regex":options.overview,"$options":"i"}},{'tag_list':{"$regex":options.overview,"$options":"i"}}];

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect for `node.js`. Try this:

```
db.options.find({

    $or:
    [ 
        { overview: wiki},
        { tag_list: wiki}
    ]
    }).exec(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
    })
```